# Arduino MQTT disconnect

Tags: arduino, mqtt, iot

I have a ESP32 board with 2 relays and a DHT22 sensor and the bellow code in Arduino running on the ESP32

MQTT Broker is running on Pi4 with mosquitto and node-red dashboard.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include "DHT.h"

#define DHTTYPE DHT22
const char* ssid = "MY SSID";
const char* password = "1234";
const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.1.118";
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

const int DHTPin = 14;
const int lamp = 25;
const int lamp1 = 26;
DHT dht(DHTPin, DHTTYPE);


long now = millis();
long lastMeasure = 0;

void setup_wifi() {
  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  delay(1000);
  WiFi.disconnect();
  delay(1000);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("WiFi connected - ESP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  String message;
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
    char c = (char)payload[i];
    message += c;
  }
  Serial.println();
  if ((char)payload[0] == '0' || message == "false") {
    digitalWrite(lamp, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(lamp1, LOW);
    Serial.println("lamp, HIGH si lamp1, LOW");
   } else if ((char)payload[0] == '1' || message == "true") {
    digitalWrite(lamp1, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(lamp, LOW);
    Serial.println("lamp, LOW si lamp1, HIGH");
  } else if ((char)payload[0] == '2') {
    digitalWrite(lamp, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(lamp1, HIGH);
    Serial.println("lamp, LOW si lamp1, LOW > STOP");
  }
}

void reconnect() {

  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    if (client.connect("ESP8266Client")) {
      Serial.println("connected");  
      // Subscribe or resubscribe to a topic
      // You can subscribe to more topics (to control more LEDs in this example)
      client.subscribe("room/lamp");
      client.subscribe("room/lamp1");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(lamp, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(lamp1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED,OUTPUT);
  dht.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
}
// For this project, you don't need to change anything in the loop function. Basically it ensures that you ESP is connected to your broker
void loop() {
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  if(!client.loop())
    client.connect("ESP8266Client");
  now = millis();
  // Publishes new temperature and humidity every 30 seconds
  if (now - lastMeasure > 5000) {
    lastMeasure = now;
    // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (its a very slow sensor)
    float h = dht.readHumidity();
    // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
    float t = dht.readTemperature();
    // Read temperature as Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
    // float f = dht.readTemperature(true);

    // Check if any reads failed and exit early (to try again).
    //if (isnan(h) || isnan(t) || isnan(f)) 
    if (isnan(h) || isnan(t)){
      Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
      return;
    }

    // Computes temperature values in Celsius
    float hic = dht.computeHeatIndex(t, h, false);
    static char temperatureTemp[7];
    dtostrf(t, 6, 2, temperatureTemp);
    static char test[7];
    dtostrf(hic, 6, 2, test);

    static char humidityTemp[7];
    dtostrf(h, 6, 2, humidityTemp);

    client.publish("room/temperature", temperatureTemp);
    client.publish("room/humidity", humidityTemp);
    client.publish("room/test", test);

    Serial.print("Humidity: ");
    Serial.print(h);
    Serial.print(" %\t Temperature: ");
    Serial.print(t);
    Serial.print(" *C ");
    //Serial.print(f);
    Serial.print(" *F\t Heat index: ");
    Serial.print(hic);
    Serial.println(" *C ");
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);
    delay(500); 
    digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
  }
}
```

The 2 relays are controlling a window in my bathroom. If  I plug the ESP32 to power all is working, and I can open/close the window and sensor readings are ok.

But after ~24hours I can still see realtime sensor readings but when I try to open/close the window nothing is happening. On the MQTT broker I can see the mqtt messages but nothing is happening.

```
room/lamp1 1
room/lamp1 1
room/lamp 0
room/lamp 0
room/lamp 0
room/lamp 0
room/lamp 0
room/lamp 0
room/temperature  24.00
room/humidity  29.10
room/test  23.22
room/lamp 0
room/lamp 0
room/lamp 2
room/lamp1 2
room/lamp 2
room/lamp1 2
room/lamp 2
room/lamp1 2
room/lamp 2
```

Any suggestions.

Comment: So do the "Message arrived [" messages stop as well, or do they still print?

Comment: Messages are arriving to mosquito server and also I can see them in the ESP32 serial, but the relays are not triggerd.